# Why does my Logcat Shows up blank after joining two tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Good Day Everyone, In my App, I Want to display on  the LogCat different Classes in a school together with their sections, i.e similar to something Like this: Class`Grade1` Sections `Grade1A, Grade1B`, Class`Grade2` Sections`Grade2A, Grade2B`etc based on the users input. I am using `Sections content` in the line `Log.i("Sections content", sb.toString());` to get the contents of the database. But the `LogCat` shows Blank/displays noting. Bellow is my source code. Why is `Logcat` displaying blank?. What am I not getting right. I have tried figuring this out through many sources for past one week but no solution. I will so much appreciate you guys.

**This code Adds a new section and displays classes together with their newly added section in the logcat**

```
private void intitializeListenersCSOS(){
        addSectionBtnID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String sectionNameValue = edittable_sectionName.getText().toString();
                String sectionDescriptionValue = edittable_sectionDescription.getText().toString();
               if( (sectionNameValue.length() > 0) && sectionDescriptionValue.length()>0){
                   sectionsBean.setSections_name(sectionNameValue);
                   sectionsBean.setSections_description(sectionDescriptionValue);
                    demeaSQL.addSections(sectionsBean,selectClassSpinner.getSelectedItemId());
                   if (demeaSQL != null) {
                   edittable_sectionName.setText("");
                   edittable_sectionDescription.setText("");
                       displayClassAndSectionsList();
                   Toast.makeText(ClassSectionOnSetup.this, "Section Added!! Add more section", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                       for (SectionsBean s : demeaSQL.getAllSectionsByClassesID()) {//getAllSections()
                           sb.append(" SectionName= " + s.getSections_name() + " SectionID= " + s.getSectionsID());
                           sb.append("\n");
                       }
                       Log.i("Sections content", sb.toString());

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   } else {
                       Log.i("Sections Err", "Database Error");
                   }


               }

            }
        });
    }
```

**DBHelperClass `addSections()`**
**Add sections to the database**

```
 public long addSections(SectionsBean sectionsBean, long selectClassID){
         long sectionid = -1;
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME, sectionsBean.getSections_name());
         values.put(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_DESCRIPTION,sectionsBean.getSections_description());
         long sectionsID = db.insert(TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS, null, values);
         if (sectionid > 0 && selectClassID > 0) {
             values.clear();
             values.put(COLUMN_CLASSLINK, selectClassID);
             values.put(COLUMN_SECTIONLINK, sectionsID);
             db.insert(TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS_LINK, null, values);
             //db.close();
         }
         return sectionid;
     }
```

**DBHelperClass `getAllSectionsByClassesID()`** 
**Get Sections based on their classes.**

```
public ArrayList<SectionsBean> getAllSectionsByClassesID(){
             String selectQuery = "SELECT " + "1 AS" + BaseColumns._ID + "," + COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME +
               "," + COLUMN_CLASSLINK +  "," + COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME + "," + COLUMN_SECTIONLINK
                + " FROM " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS_LINK +
               " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CLASSES + " ON " + TABLE_CLASSES + "." + COLUMN_CLASSES_ID +
                " = " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS_LINK + "." + COLUMN_CLASSLINK +
              " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS + " ON " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS + "." +
                COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID + " = " + TABLE_CLASSES_SECTIONS_LINK + "." + COLUMN_SECTIONLINK ;
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<SectionsBean> sectionsBeanList = new ArrayList<SectionsBean>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        Log.i("Query details", String.valueOf(cursor));
        Log.d("DataDetails", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ClassesBean classesBean = new ClassesBean();
            classesBean.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_ID)));
            classesBean.setClasses_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_NAME)));
            SectionsBean sectionsBean = new SectionsBean();
            sectionsBean.setSectionsID(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_ID)));
            sectionsBean.setSections_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLASSES_SECTIONS_NAME)));
            sectionsBean.setClassesBean(classesBean);
            sectionsBeanList.add(sectionsBean);

        }
        return sectionsBeanList;

    }
```

Comment: are you sure you are selecting option `Info` while viewing logcat?

Comment: yeah exactly am doing that @Sam

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your logcat while running or debugging an application here?

Comment: it is just blank, it shows noting when I filter to `Sections content`, no error message.

Comment: what is selected in the last drop down?

Comment: Dont really understand. But I selected `info` @Sam

Comment: @Sam I mean What do you mean by last dropdown?

Comment: Split the problem. Add a Log.i somewhere where you know it will add a line to the Log. Run, if you don't see the line then the cause will be how you are displaying the log cat other wise the issue is in you code, so progressively add Log.i's. Of course it could be quicker to add breakpoints and use debugger.